# How to write Spark Structured Streaming Data into Hive?

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-2.0

How to write Spark Structured Streaming Data into Hive?

There is `df.write().saveAsTable(tablename)` however I am not sure if this writes streaming data

I normally do `df.writeStream().trigger(new ProcessingTime(1000)).foreach(new KafkaSink()).start()` to write streaming data into Kafka but I don't see anything similar to write streaming data into Hive data warehouse. any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
df.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable") 
spark.sql("create table mytable as select * from mytable");
```

or

```
df.write().mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).saveAsTable("dbName.tableName");
```

Comment: if you want to add data in to same table so you have to used .mode(SaveMode.append).

Comment: I think the question seeks information about how to write a streaming data into hive. Your solution is for batch data.