# Spark Structured Streaming - Insert into existing Hive table with scalability without errors

Tags: apache-spark, hive, spark-structured-streaming

This seems like a fairly straight-forward thing to do and you would think the Spark developers would have built in a way to do this but I could not find one. Options I have seen or tried are:

1. Write to Parquet file and create external hive table but I want to insert into existing Hive internal table. I know I can add this data simply using another spark job to periodically add this data but that is not ideal
2. Write a custom `ForeachWriter` which I have tried with limited success:

   ```scala
   val ds1 = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", hostPort).option("subscribe", "test").load()
   val lines = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(value AS STRING)").as[String]
   val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))

   import org.apache.spark.sql.ForeachWriter
   val writer = new ForeachWriter[String] {
     import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
     override def open(partitionId: Long, version: Long) = true
     override def process(value: String) = {
         val sparksess = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
         import sparksess.implicits._
         val valData = List(value).toDF
         valData.write.mode("append").insertInto("stream_test") 
         sparksess.close
         }
     override def close(errorOrNull: Throwable) = {}
   }
   val q = words.writeStream.queryName("words-app").foreach(writer)
   val query = q.start()
   ```

NOTE: It would seem obvious to create Sparksession in the Open method and close the session in the close method but these did not work for more than one iteration then failed

Note: The above worked even past first iteration but there are Spark errors being thrown that do not make me comfortable that this solution will scale:

```
18/03/15 11:10:52 ERROR cluster.YarnScheduler: Lost executor 2 on hadoop08.il.nds.com: Container marked as failed: container_1519892135449_0122_01_000003 on host: hadoop08.il.nds.com. Exit status: 50. Diagnostics: Exception from container-launch.
Container id: container_1519892135449_0122_01_000003
Exit code: 50
Stack trace: ExitCodeException exitCode=50:
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.runCommand(Shell.java:601)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.run(Shell.java:504)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell$ShellCommandExecutor.execute(Shell.java:786)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.DefaultContainerExecutor.launchContainer(DefaultContainerExecutor.java:213)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:302)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.nodemanager.containermanager.launcher.ContainerLaunch.call(ContainerLaunch.java:82)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)


Container exited with a non-zero exit code 50
```

Note: There was a similar question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45796006/how-to-write-spark-structured-streaming-data-into-hive): 
But the answer does not say how it is do the Streaming context and was left unanswered

Can anyone help fix this code so that it scales better without errors?

3. Write back to a Kafka sink and then have Kafka write to Hive using KafkaConnect like it says [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48631622/apache-spark-structured-streaming-datastreamwriter-write-to-hive-table): 
   However, I want to avoid this extra complexity.
4. Write to JDBCSink - this will be my next attempt but it seems like it should not be necessary for Hive within Spark!!
5. I have read that DataBricks is developing something similar - see [here](https://forums.databricks.com/answers/13602/view.html):

But it is not clear when and if this will be released as part of standard Spark GA release.

Any help especially from Spark developers regarding the best way to accomplish stream-writing data to existing Hive tables would be very much appreciated.

**Edit**:

I wrote a JDBC Sink extending the ForeachWriter and it works but it is very slow since it has to open and close a connection for each row! I wanted to try to create a connection pool that would reuse and release connections but read that it was not possible with the ForeachWriter and that I would have to write my own custom JDBC sink to do this and that it was complicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47130229/spark-2-2-struct-streaming-foreach-writer-jdbc-sink-lag).

I am planning on one of 2 options 1. For the sake of simplicity and until Spark releases a built-in solution, write out data to parquet file accessible by hive external table and write job to periodically to move data to managed table. 2. Use older Spark Streaming DStream which seems to have ability to use ForeachRDD to lazily create singleton sessions that can be reused but then I assume I would lose the "exactly once" features of Structured Streaming and would have to completely rewrite my code when this capability is built into Structured Streaming.